# Error not found for object and value in Scala Unit Testing

Tags: scala, unit-testing, class, methods

I want to run a unit test named TestEnterNumbers.scala on the following class. I tried running the following but I am getting error: not found: object controller for `import controller.Actions.Number` and error: not found: value controller  `assert(controller.Actions.Number(changeNum, 1) == 1)`.

Directory

```
   src
    |_ changeNum
        |_ controller
        |    |_ Actions.scala
        |_ model
        |    |_ ChangeNum.scala
        |_ tests
            |_ TestEnterNumbers.scala
```

TestEnterNumbers.scala

```
package changeNum.tests

import org.scalatest._
import controller.Actions.Number

class TestEnterNumbers extends FunSuite{
test("Use many test cases for ChangeNum"){
    assert(controller.Actions.Number(changeNum, 0) == 0)
    assert(controller.Actions.Number(changeNum, 223) == 223)
    assert(controller.Actions.Number(changeNum, 4061) == 4061)
    assert(controller.Actions.Number(changeNum, 99806) == 99806)
}
}
```

ChangeNum.scala

```
class ChangeNum() {

def current(): Double = {
    0.0
}
}
```

Actions.scala

```
package changeNum.controller

import javafx.event.ActionEvent
import javafx.event.EventHandler

class Number(changeNum: ChangeNum, number: Int) extends 
EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
var changeNumber = changeNum.toString
override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
changeNumber.concat(number.toString)
changeNumber.toDouble
}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect comparing `Number(changeNum, 99806) == 99806`? It's not a type safe comparison and may return wrong result

Answer (score 1):

In your `TestEnterNumbers.scala`

```
// to access case class Number
import changeNum.controller.Number
```

Remember: In Scala, folder structor doesn't matter if your not applying it with your `package` path. So, Scala compiler will always look at `package` path.

Comment: I am getting error: object Number is not a member of package changeNum.controller
Note: class Number exists, but it has no companion object.
for  assert(changeNum.controller.Number(changeNum, 0) == 0)

Comment: @thelegend27 Use `new` operator like `new controller.Actions.Number(changeNum, 0)`